# Trouble reading a char array in java. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm getting the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" when I try to read an array value. Here is the code that I think causes the error.

```
        class Board
{
    private static char[][] board;

    public Board(int r, int c)
    {
        setRow(r);
        setColumn(c);
        char board[][] = new char[row][column];
    }

    public void getBoard()
    {
        for (int c = 1;c <= getColumn()-1 ;c++)
        {
            System.out.print("\t"+c);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        for (int r = 1; r <= getRow()-1; r++)
        {
            System.out.print(r);
            for (int c = 1; c <= getColumn(); c++)
            {
                System.out.print("\t" + board[r][c]);  //I think board[r][c] is causing it.
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

I can upload the whole file if need be.

Any help would be appreciated, this kept me up last night.

Comment: add a `-1` to the last `for` loop, `for (int c = 1; c <= getColumn()-1; c++)` 
`

Comment: Also, a "getXxx" method that doesn't return anything is misleading.  You should probably call this "printBoard".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
char board[][] = new char[row][column];
```

with

```
board = new char[row][column];
```

In the first statement, you're assigning a value to a local variable, not to the one of your instance.

Comment: Thanks that did it! Saved the day.

Answer (score 1):

You are hiding member variable in the constructor

```
char board[][] = new char[row][column];
```

it should be

```
 board= new char[row][column];
```